# shortening complex css selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to shorten some css selectors for ease of reading
for example:

```
.a>.c,.b>.c
```

I thought I had used parenthesis in the past to group the union before continuing with more selectors

```
(.a,.b)>.c
```

But it seems this is not valid css.

Did I dream that I have done this before or is there a simple way?

My primary concern is readability of the css rather than number of bytes, however that is another obvious advantage to shortening the selector as above.

Comment: In plain CSS no, parenthesis are not valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parenthesis aren't used like this in CSS. Please see the [Selectors Level 3 W3C Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/).

If `.c` is only ever the child of `.a` and `.b` you can simply use:

```css
.c { }
```

If `.a` and `.b` differ from `.x` (assuming `.x` has a `.c` child), you can give them a specific class or [data-* attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes):

```html
<div class="a t" <!-- or --> data-t><span class="c"></span></div>
<div class="b t" <!-- or --> data-t><span class="c"></span></div>
<div class="x"><span class="c"></span></div>
```

And style using:

```css
.t > .c { }
/* Or */
[data-t] > .c { }
```

Otherwise, there's nothing greatly *unreadable* about what you already have. If you want to make it even easier to read, simply space it out a little and put each selector on a new line:

```css
.a > .c,
.b > .c {
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed explaination.
The question was probably somewhat over-simplified. In my real-world scenario ".c" is actually "h1".
I wanted to avoid adding a class to every h1.
In my specific real-world example it's actually quite simple anyway but I can see it coming up again.

Comment: In that case you can simply use H1. `.a > h1, .b > h1 { }`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`:is` pseudo selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) to shorten selectors which are similar but with different combinations, so each selector *inside* the `:is()` is combined with what comes *after* the `:is()`:

```css
:is(.a, .b) > .c { color: red }
```

```html
<div class='a'>
  <a class='c'>a > c</a>
</div>
<div class='b'>
  <a class='c'>b > c</a>
</div>
<div class='a'>
  <a class='b'>a > b</a>
</div>
<div class='c'>
  <a class='c'>c > c</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Last time I checked browser support for `:is` was still limited. Certainly back when this question was asked we didn't have it, but going forward this will definitly be the way to do it.

Comment: Support is well established for a few years now. I think this should be the accepted answer nowadays

Comment: According to https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ais browser support is currently at ~ 92%

Comment: You should check browser support according to the users' profile of your app/website. Browser support might be 100% or close then ;)